# SQL Get Other Rows From Aggregate Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an aggregate function that does a group by (col A).  It selects the maximum value from a set of columns(col B), but I also want to return another value from a column in the same row(col C).  But if it groups 3 rows it selects the first value from column C not the column with the maximum (MAX(col B)).

```
A    B    C
1     75  jkl
1    100  abc
1    125  dae
2    200  def
3    300  ghi

"SELECT A, MAX(B), C FROM myTable where B > 50 GROUP BY A"

returns (first row) A => 1, B => 125, C => jkl

I want it to return 

A => 1, B => 125, C => dae
```

Comment: How does your query even run???  If you are not aggregating `C`, how would you know which ones to pick?  Query definitely won't run in any other dbms.  The first solution would be to write a proper query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will want to use a subquery that will get the `max(b)` by each `A` and then join that value back to your table to return the remaining columns that match the values of the subquery:

```
select *
from mytable t1
inner join
(
  select A, max(b) B
  from mytable
  where b >50
  group by a
) t2
  on t1.a = t2.a
  and t1.b = t2.b
where t1.b >50
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60347/3)

Comment: are nested SQL queries faster than say just collecting the MAX(B)'s and then running a single query for each of the MAX(B)'s?

Comment: @TheHawk I don't understand what you are asking, can you clarify?

Comment: if I run the nested query by itself I get a result set with all  max(b)'s.  I loop through the result set of max(b)'s and run a select for each max(b).  Basically the same thing as a nested query but kind of doing it manually

Comment: @TheHawk there would be no need to loop through the result when this gets you everything in one query. This query should be faster.

Comment: Note that this solution will return multiple results if there are multiple rows with the same max value; for example if B of the third record were 100, not 125.  If that's what you want, great; but if you want exactly one max record per group, see my post below.

Answer (score 5):

since you haven't mention the RDBMS you are using, use this query which works on almost all RDBMS

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  A, MAX(b) max_B
            FROM    tableName
            WHERE   b > 50
            GROUP   BY A
        ) b ON a.A = b.A   AND
            a.B = b.max_B
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec81f/2)

But if your RDBMS support window functions, you can use `DENSE_RANK()`

```
SELECT  A, B, C
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  A, B, C,
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION A ORDER BY B DESC) rn
            FROM    tableName
            WHERE   b > 50
            GROUP   BY      
        ) a
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: are nested SQL queries faster than say just collecting the MAX(B)'s and then running a single query for each of the MAX(B)'s?

Comment: It will be more efficient if you will add compound index on column A and B.

Comment: Thanks for the DENSE_RANK note. Had the same question but for SQL Server

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common problem: "show me other columns on the rows matching my min()/max() criteria." On large tables, subquery or rank function strategies usually *scan* the entire table and can become very slow.

If you're willing to get your head around it, this is by far the most performant way to handle this (though not the most readable):

```
SELECT A, cast(left(val, 8) as int) AS B, substring(val, 9, 999) AS C
FROM ( SELECT A, max(str(B, 8) + C) AS val FROM myTable GROUP BY A) t
```

You can concatenate anything to what you're `max`ing as long as you concatenate the same length before the final field (hence `str` function's leading spaces to sort numerical values correctly), then extract it in the outer query. All index-friendly. Voilá.

Note that this will return different (and I think better) results than the solutions posted by bluefeet and JW, in that if there are multiple matching max values per group, this method will pick a winner (the largest C) whereas the others will return multiple records.  So, if the 3rd B value were 100 instead of 125, this will return **1, 100, dae** whereas the other solutions would return both **1, 100, abd** and **1, 100, dae**.

Comment: This looks great. However, C is taken into account when the MAX function runs. It's MAXing over C as well, but I believe he wants the associated C value to "the MAXimum B for a particular A". That means in a tie, the query should have two results. This is because we are not supposed ot take the value of C into account.