# similar to last() in sql, what can i use in derby database?

Tags: sql, derby, javadb

`Select Last(column_name) from table_name` will return the last value in the column in standard SQL. What is a similar query that will work in derby to fetch the last value in the column?

Please find the sample table below: 'secondcol' is the column name in the table.

```
          secondcol
          33
          45
          78
```

`Select Last(secondcol) from table_name` in sql will return 78 as output. If i want to get similar output in javadb/derby database, how can i query it? I don't want to change any order in the column values.

Comment: `SELECT secondCol FROM tableName ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` maybe?

Comment: Define the last value? Do you mean the most recently inserted value? The LAST() function is not supported by many database engines.

Comment: Yes I mean the most recently inserted value and I want to get it without the need of unique key values like primary key column.

Answer (score 4):

To select last row in table is little bit different then it is in pure SQL:

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

DERBY:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Have a nice day ;)

Comment: In my case, DESC had to be removed

Answer (score 1):

Is there some unique key on the table where you could form the question as "give me the *secondcol* value on the row with the max *key* value"?  If so, there is a technique that will work in any database engine - the idea is to concatenate the key plus any desired result data, perform a min/max, then extract the result data.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14881009/1800725) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005382/1800725).

Comment: I want most recently inserted value in the column without depending on unique key on the table.

Comment: To get the most-recently-inserted row, add a generated column with an auto-incrementing counter in it. Then select the row with the MAX value of that column.