# SUM of rows with max date

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

Hope you can help me with this one. Supose I have a table which looks like this (sorry, but my reputation isn't high enough to post images):

```
[ACCOUNT] [PROGRAM] [DATE] [AMOUNT]

[500] [P1] [10/10/2014] [4.2]
[500] [P2] [09/08/2010] [5.1]
[501] [P1] [08/02/2010] [2.3]
[501] [P3] [10/11/2014] [9.2]
```

Now, grouping by account, I want to sum the amounts, while keeping the program belonging to the latest date. I want to achieve this, in Oracle SQL:

```
[ACCOUNT] [PROGRAM] [AMOUNT]

[500] [P1] [9.3] 
[501] [P3] [11.5]
```

Could anybody lend me a hand, please?
Thank you very much!

Comment: `select sum(amount), max(date), .... group by account`?

Comment: @Marc B, I think he wants the PROGRAM related to the MAX(DATE).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.account, b.program, a.amount FROM
(SELECT account, SUM(amount) as amount from table) a INNER JOIN
(SELECT account, program FROM table t 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM table 
     WHERE account = t.account and date > t.date)) b 
  ON a.account = b.account
```

or this might also work:

```
SELECT t.account, t.program, t.amount 
FROM
(SELECT account, program, SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY account, program), date  
 FROM table) t 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT* from table 
    WHERE account = t.account and date > t.date) b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem that no one has a great answer for: "*Show me other columns on the rows matching my min()/max() aggregate criteria.*" If this is a big table and performance counts, nothing can touch the approach I outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14881009/1800725) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005382/1800725).  Try:

```
select account
     , program = substr(val, 9)
     , date = to_date(substr(val, 1, 8))
     , amount
from (  select account
             , amount = sum(amount)
             , val = max(to_char(date, 'YYYYMMDD') + program)  --latest date plus other data you want glued together in a sortable string
        from yourtable 
        group by account) t
```

My apologies if my Oracle syntax is off - I'm a T-SQL guy.